# flutter run throwing error because of simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I'm really really new to using Macbook, my first time actually.

I have developed a Flutter app on a Windows machine and everything worked fine on the Android emulator.

I can't get it to work when trying to run the same app on Mac. I already tried most of the answers found here or on any other website.

I followed the steps described on the official Flutter website to set up Flutter for Mac, but it's not working.

Due to the fact that as far as I know, XCode doesn't support Flutter yet and being more familiar with VSCode, I was planning to use this IDE as well as its terminal.

After following the steps on the Flutter website I keep getting the following error when running `flutter run`:

```
Error (Xcode): File not found:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/u
sr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a


Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

Couldn't find a helpful answer yet, which could make my app work.

I don't really know which information would be relevant to solve this issue, but here are a couple of tool versions I'm using:

- macOS: Ventura 13.3.1
- Flutter Version: 3.7.0
- Simulator: iPhone 14 Pro Max with iOS version 16.4

Any answer would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

can you try to run these commands in your project path? (on VSCode)

1. flutter pub cache repair
2. flutter clean
3. flutter pub get
4. cd ios && pod install --repo-update && cd ..

and run project again

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I'm still receiving the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like upgrading flutter from `3.7.10` to `3.7.11` did the trick for me and fixed the issue.

For further references just run

```
flutter upgrade
```